# How could I know the code in the bob like bob.pipelines.CheckpointWrapper?

Tags: python-bob

How to access the code in the bob? Like,I want to know the return of *bob.pipelines.CheckpointWrapper*. But I just find the Parameters Interpretation.

Note: Bob is a free signal-processing and machine learning toolbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USerm.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the source code of Bob packages in their Gitlab repository: https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob

For example, the class you pointed out is located in this file: https://gitlab.idiap.ch/bob/bob.pipelines/-/blob/master/bob/pipelines/wrappers.py